# Browser localStorage refreshing at every page

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache

I have coded a pop-up div which I want to display once per visit to the website per user, for which I was able to piece together as follows, but unfortunately it seems to pop-up at every single page I visit on the website:

```
//COOKIE POLICY POP-UP
$(document).ready(function () {

if (localStorage.getItem('pops') != 'visible') {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#cookie_popup').css('bottom', '0');
    }, 1000);

    $('#cookie_popup a.button').click(function () {
        $('#cookie_popup').css('bottom', '-100px');
    });

    localStorage.setItem('pops', 'visible');
}

});

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    localStorage.removeItem('pops');
};
```

Edit: As pointed on the comments below, the last section window.onbeforeunload needed to be removed for it to keep the cache for the whole session.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = function () { localStorage.removeItem('pops');};` is removing the flag so that every time you come to the page, the flag isn't there and the popup is shown. Remove that part and make sure you manually clear `localStorage` yourself before you test.

Comment: Thank you @ScottMarcus you are right. I tried without and it worked.
If you'd like to write your comment as an answer I'll be able to upvote it.
Thank you so much for taking the time to help me, really appreciated!

Comment: about the comment above: that is the expected behavior, closing the browser doesn't clean the localStorage, just the sessionStorage, to clean the localstorage, you must clear the browser cache and etc...

Comment: That is true, I have tested it again according to the first comment and it worked.
Thank you for your comment @CalvinNunes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () { localStorage.removeItem('pops');};
```

is removing the flag so that every time you come to the page, the flag isn't there and the popup is shown. Remove that part and make sure you manually clear `localStorage` yourself before each of your tests.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @ScottMarcus